# Postgresql query date format with sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes, date-conversion

I'm trying with following query, it is giving me the correct date format but dates are not sorted correctly.

```
select to_char(date_of_service, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as service_date 
from cases 
order by service_date
```

Result I'm getting something like this (sample).

```
"01/01/2005"
"01/01/2010"
"01/02/2005"
"01/02/2010"
```

After date format I think it is getting converted into string and due to that sorting is not working. Any alternate solution available for this?

Comment: use  `order by date_of_service`

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting by the string value, not the real date value. So you need to change your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select to_char(date_of_service, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as service_date 
from cases 
order by date_of_service;
```